# Let's design some new ads!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

For the past two years we have run community-promotion ads on other SE sites (graduated only), promoting this community.  The current ad we're using is this:

[image: our ad for other communities]

In addition, now that *we* have graduated we can run ads on our *own* site. Candidate ad topics include:

- the blog (direct link to the blog, to encourage readership)
- *writing* for the blog, maybe something like [this EL&U ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxH6z.png)
- the sandbox, aimed at new askers
- any external resources that we have found useful for worldbuilding (map-making sites, for example)

Either way, we need **images** for these ads.  And we can't just reuse last year's, because **the size requirements have changed**.  Community ads will now be 300px wide by 250px high.

So, what ads do we want to make, both for ourselves and to run elsewhere?  Do you have ideas for art to fit the new size requirements?  Please share.

Soon there will be a separate post calling for submissions for community-promotion ads.  This is not that post.  I'm posting this now so that people can get started with drafting ads and adjusting -- or replacing, if we think it's time for a change -- our current external ad.

Comment: That image, by the way, is fantastic.  That planet clearly had something terrifying happen to it.  Rethemed it makes a great "in construction" look.

Comment: @Draco18s It looks like it could be a paint-over of the Death Star 2: http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/e/ee/DeathStar2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150615015212  The shapes of the missing, scarred, and darkened areas are uncannily similar.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson I wondered if that was the case, but I wasn't entirely sure.

Answer (score 12):

This is a proposal for an alternate ad to use in conjunction with [this one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4786/6507) (as in, use both, but on different sites). I was thinking this could be used as a replacement for the ad on RPG.SE. 
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Ad currently used (in 2017) on

- [SciFi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10566/41082)
- [RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6728)

See [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4396/suggestion-for-new-worldbuilding-ad-for-sff-se) for community's approval.

[image]

Comment: I have just posted this one [to Game Dev Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2630/2698) for their 2018 ads.

Answer (score 10):

[image: World In Progress]

This is the original ad slightly modified to fit the new size requirements.

[Submitted on RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6033/19667)

Comment: The folks from RPG asked us about a new ad for their site.  I move that we go ahead and submit this there.

Comment: @MonicaCellio go for it; if we come up with a better one we can always re-submit.

Comment: And we're live on RPG.  That was fast!

Comment: We should submit it on writers as well, maybe some other places?

Comment: @TimE feel free to submit it on any communities you see fit.

Answer (score 9):

[image: external ad]

Candidate external ad, based on an example in a highly-voted design suggestion.

**Update:** So far I've been unable to confirm usage rights on the image.  It's on a bunch of "download free wallpaper" sites, but that's not the same as republishing and it's not attributed.

Comment: Link to previous thread: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2848/10851

Answer (score 6):

Another idea for the blog:

[image]

Wording mostly stolen from the EL&U blog ad; images are two header images from our blog, and the blog logo (which I have high-res versions of, if anybody wants one to make an ad with).

Font is [Fairview](http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=fairview), which is the font our logo is based off.

Comment: I really like that :)

Comment: I suggest adding this to the [call for community ads](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2902/28), where if it reaches 6 votes it'll be part of the rotation.

Comment: @MonicaCellio done

Answer (score 3):

My artistic skills are non-existent, so I cobbled this together in Paint just as an illustration of concept, or to inspire someone with better art skills, *not* intended to be a final design.

[image]

The idea is for advertising the Worldbuilding Sandbox.  The intention is to show a pair of hands sculpting a globe within a child's sandbox.  At the top, the globe should look finished, then fade in level of detail toward the bottom, where it is just sand.  The globe could be earth-like, but would probably be better as an abstract fantasy globe.

Comment: Cool idea.  It'll also need some text -- something like "want help developing your question? try the sandbox!" but less verbose probably.

Comment: What about "Building a question?" for the text.

Comment: I am creating an SVG image of this, where the globe will be easily substitutable for other globes, such as an abstract fantasy globe.

Comment: @wizzwizz4:  Awesome!  Can't wait to see.  Feel free to add as an edit here, if you choose.

Comment: We could maybe use the new logo from the site design thread as the planet in this image once the site design is finalized.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work for the Universe Factory:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've now managed to add metadata (mainly the information about used images; IIUC needed to comply with the license, since the community ad doesn't have additional descriptive text to it) to the image; the following is the resulting file (visually identical, but with metadata):

[image]

Images used in the creation of this:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Andromeda_Galaxy_%28with_h-alpha%29.jpg
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:P_writing.svg
- The logo of Universe Factory (copied directly from the page)

Comment: OK, I've added now another version based on version 2, with "dark glow" around all text, and "The Worldbuilding community blog" as text (it's now two lines).

Comment: I've now added also a suggestion for the version asking for contributors.

Comment: Glow is perfect, brings out the logo. Text on first might be good bigger. Text on second maybe. "Contributors wanted. The worldbuilding community blog."

Comment: Thanks for the updates!  I agree with Tim that the glow is perfect.  I wonder if we should make the blog ad and the blog-writers-wanted ad a little more different from each other, just so people don't pattern-match the art and blog logo and miss that they're different.  Swapping the text and logo, or putting "contributors wanted" above the logo (so moving it down a bit) could do the trick.  These are just ideas; I'm not a graphic designer.  Thanks again for your work on this!

Comment: Maybe go with the ArtOfCode one for contributing and use this one to advertise the blog itself?

Comment: I suggest adding #4 ("the Worldbuilding community blog") to the [call for community ads](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2902/28); if it reaches 6 votes there it'll be live.

Comment: @TimB: I've now added a new version of the blog ad with bigger text. I didn't make a new version of the contribution ad, as ArtOfCode's ad is already on the call-for-ads page.

Comment: Looks great :) nice one

Comment: Looks great!  Want to go ahead and add that last one as an answer to the call for community ads?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Done. Mouseover Tagline: Visit Universe Factory

Answer (score 3):

And here's a general ad for Worldbuilding:

[image]

Background image is from a blog that says all its posts are public domain. Main font is once again [Fairview](http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=fairview), secondary font is Quartz MS.

[Posted on SciFi, on the suggestion of a few people in chat](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7993/52927).

Comment: While I do really like this I agree with the comment from sci-fi that the "Welcome to Oskeron" text distracts from the main message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a picture, but I do have a suggestion.

*"Brave the wild sands of raw questions and use the Sandbox!"*

Just an idea to make a wordplay with "Sandbox."