# Suggestion for new Worldbuilding ad for SFF.SE

Tags: discussion

So, it's the time of the year to re-vote for Community Promotion ads on all the Stack Exchange sites. And while the ad we ran on Science Fiction & Fantasy last year was pretty good, I thought maybe I could do better. The following image is my attempt to prove that hypothesis:

[image: This is why we can't have nice things.]

I tried to incorporate some elements of our site design (colors, the robot/human on the side), and also appeal to fans of science fiction (Douglas Adams and exploding planets).

Before posting it on SFF's meta, I just wanted to get the community's blessing, and/or see if anyone had any suggestions for improvements.

**Based on the below answers, I have posted the updated image to Meta SFF. I will update as needed if any adjustments are suggested. **

Comment: This is personal taste, but maybe some flashier colors?

Comment: @PatJ I'm trying to match the palette of the main site. So... maybe I can touch it up a bit, but I don't want to go too far

Comment: I posted [last year's version there already](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10566/410829). I'd rather have this version than that one, so I can delete that answer if you want, or you can edit this image in place of the first one. Either way, I think this great.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Oooh, subtle.

Comment: Can you make it 600x500 for high DPI screens?

Comment: @curiousdannii yeah, looks like I can. It started out over the size limit, but I guess 2/3rds of the data was unnecessary.

Comment: Looks fantastic! Only thing now is that it looks like there's some 1px artefact on the right side at the top.

Comment: @curiousdannii yep, good catch, fixed that and some stars that were bothering me (they all bother me, but some less than others).

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh they are not the stars, eh, they are Dalek's, and the earth was destroyed just by a misshit.

Answer (score 10):

## Option 1: Replace the current proposal

[There is currently a proposal to re-use the design from last year](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10566/46611). Vote for this answer if we want to remove that proposed design and replace it with this one.

Comment: I like the new proposal and think the Oskeron reference is confusing in the old one, I like this option.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 2: Make a new proposal

[There is currently a proposal to re-use the design from last year](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10566/46611). Vote for this answer if we want to leave that proposed design and make a new one, and see what SFF votes for.

Answer (score -6):

## Option 3: Don't change the current proposal

[There is currently a proposal to re-use the design from last year](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10566/46611). Vote for this answer if we want to leave that one and not use this new design at all. :(