# Sandbox promotion and awareness

Tags: discussion, sandbox

I see Codegolf is running ads for its sandbox.

[image: ad]

Why don’t we do that?

**If making ads, note that the [required dimensions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5801/28) are 600x500 px (or 300x250).**

Comment: I love that idea and would love to see ads that encourage new users to give it a try! I am not very creative, but maybe I will give it a try later...

Comment: Ours needs sandworms, though.

Comment: I'm thinking about something like "Don't know how to ask? Fix your bugs in the Sandbox!" and then a giant insect sitting in a Sandbox with someone attaching a band-aid to its wing. Though the term "bugs" might be too far away from WorldBuilding and would be better on SO, PPCG or similar sites.

Comment: Still Needs work.

Comment: Yeah... Just posting a few ideas in the comments in case someone creative reads them and takes them as a starting point. Maybe a confused construction worker looking at a half-done planet like [this one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2912/28789) with a text like "Don't know how to ask? Check out the Sandbox!"? (... I'll stop with the ideas for now.)

Comment: Probably because no one made one. :-)  Yeah, if people work out an ad concept and create the ad, by all means add it to [the post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4377/28)!

Comment: Having a sandcastle in construction would fit well.

Comment: I wish there was a way to post a bounty for meta questions.  This one deserves it.  By the way, what are the graphic requirements?  A large box with small text is awful easy to create.

Comment: I like @Vincent 's idea quite a bit. I get the feeling this is just a thing where people post different ideas and vote on them below, but I might steal this one and make a quick mockup when I get home.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: Hey Renan, you should post this in the [Community Promotion Ads for 2018](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/community-promotion-ads-2018).  We need to raise awareness of the sandbox, and this is a great ad.

Comment: @Gryphon thanks, I'll do it when I get home later :)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: "Question" is spelt wrong, but this is my favourite of the three tbh.

Comment: @F1Krazy, Hah!  it was late.  I've corrected the original.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: You should have asked  in the sandbox before posting this qustion. Just to proof read it.

Comment: @Vincent... Man!  This is a hard house!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: The only real downside to this image (and the other too) it that the text is missing [anti-aliasing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/correct-anti-aliasing-color-when-moving-to-a-new-background) and looks jagged.

Answer (score 3):

[image]