# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's amazing blog
- useful tools or resources for understanding worlds
- blogs or articles of existing interesting worlds
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5801).

Comment: Traditionally, we would post a sample ad with the site's twitter, but unfortunately Worldbuilding does not have a twitter account. [Here's an example of one, though](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4131/community-promotion-ads-2018/4132#4132).

Comment: WB has [a blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory/) maybe that would work for a sample add?

Comment: @MonicaCellio looking at the body of the q and their comment about us not having a twitter I wager there is some customization done

Comment: @dot_Sp0T oh yeah, I guess you're right.  Sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to create an ad that is user-centric?  For example, I was considering an ad that invited users to remember to select a best answer.  The page that ad should go to is the users profile, question tab (in my specific case, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40609/jbh?tab=questions) so they can see what has and hasn't been answered.  It's the "40609/jbh" part that would need to be unique to the user viewing the ad graphic.  Can SE build links on-the-fly in this way?

Answer (score 18):

[image: Writing.SE]

Comment: Please repost on the [2019 ads post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7063/28) when you get a chance.  Thanks!

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Done. TY.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Q&A about works of sci-fi and fantasy!]

Comment: Copied from [last year](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4432/2235); ad designed by [CreationEdge](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10595/31394).

Answer (score 13):

[image: Visit Universe Factory, our community-run blog!]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Share your work on the blog -- we'll help!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Built Your World? Now Build Your Language! (ConLang)]

Comment: I like the idea of incorporating "Built your world? Now build your language!" into the ad.  However, this post doesn't follow the requirements given in the question; the image is the wrong size/scale and doesn't have any text.  I hope you'll remedy that so we can vote on this ad.  (Right now, even if it reaches 6 votes, the SE engine won't pick it up.)

Comment: @FoxElemental - In order for this to work as an ad, you cannot have the "extra" stuff in there. Leave the image and the markup for the links and that's it. I don't think it will work if you have anything else in there (such as the text below the image). I tried to edit it for you, but it won't let me. No clue why it has an "edit" link below the post, lol.

Comment: Corrected image: This is an adapted form of an image similar to Duncan Whyte's image, but slightly modified. Adapted from [this answer](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/designing-an-ad-for-conlang-se) by elemtilas. Phrase adapted from the "[Built Your World? Now Build Your Story!](https://writing.stackexchange.com/)" ad. Most of the credit goes to @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 who resized the image and added text.

Comment: Saw and voted. :-)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Get inspired by reading, at Literature SE!]

Comment: Copied from [last year](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4382/2235); ad mostly designed by [BESW](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/a/423/17).

Answer (score 6):

[image: The best questions are perfected first in our Sandbox!]

Comment: Please note that [Rube Goldberg's "Self-Operating Napkin" is considered public domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Self-operating_napkin_(Rube_Goldberg_cartoon_with_caption).jpg).

Comment: I removed my upvote because of the edit.  The ad should point to the sandbox page we are all using, not the one you're trying to create that isn't ready for new users yet.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'd done the same with my vote; JBH has reverted the link since.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hmmm... out of curiosity, if an ad passes the 6-vote threshold and begins to be used on the site, and then later is downvotted below the 6-vote threshold, is it still used or does that deactivate the use of the ad?

Comment: @JBH it drops back out of the rotation until it has a qualifying score again.  This is probably checked roughly daily, not immediately.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Help in the Sandbox as a Mentor!]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tower of Babel with SE colours.]

Comment: Pretty cool, alas it looks like a certain emoji :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Answer (score -4):

[image: Discover the universe]

Comment: With the best of compliments to Mme.Curie

Comment: Maybe the downvoter has some feedback I could use :)

Comment: The phrase "one weird trick" tends to attract knee-jerk downvoting from people who dislike clickbait headlines.

Comment: I think the Physics.SE should be bigger. It's hard to see, and I agree with Mark that if you miss the Physics.SE text, it looks like clickbait.