# Does our site ask people who haven't upvoted a question in a while to upvote questions?

Tags: support, questions, up-votes

On other sites, especially those I haven't visited in a while (weeks to months), I'll get a screen-wide drop-down that says something along the lines of, "you haven't upvoted any questions in a while, remember OPs need love too!"

I've not seen that here, but maybe I'm active enough that I never see it.  I was prompted to ask this question by [a comment left by @willk, encouraging upvotes to the question.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/135969/will-a-civilization-need-to-make-weapons-if-their-use-of-magic-is-limitless#comment422677_135969)  Which I thought was a good idea.

I'd create a [community promotion ad](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/community-promotion-ads-2018), but those require too much effort to get the necessary traction.

Do we have an automated "hey!  Upvote a question why doncha!" as I've seen on other sites?

Answer (score 4):

The "Welcome back!" banner is only shown under specific circumstances, as outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89059/323179):

> The message [...] only appears if
>
> - you haven't been seen on the target site for 24 hours, and
> - you hold a valid user cookie on the target site, and
> - your account has more than 15 rep on the target site, and
> - you arrive on a question from a search engine, and
> - you have not already voted on this particular question and answers

For this message, you're probably not getting it either because you don't ever get to this site via a search engine or you're here every day.

---

There's also another message:

> [I]f you haven’t voted on at least one question in the last 15 votes you cast — you’ll now get the **“you haven’t voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too!” reminder** every time you vote until you do.

This comes from the [Vote For This Question or The Kitten Gets It](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/06/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) blog post, which tells us that the best way to get people to vote for questions is blackmail that threatens one or more kittens.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I don't meet the condition of bullet #4 99.99% of the time.

Comment: I think you're talking about the banner that appears at the top of a page that says "welcome back" and talks about voting.  I thought the question was about the pop-up you sometimes get when voting on an answer that says "you haven't voted on questions in a while".  @JBH, could you clarify which message you're asking about?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, There are two?  (\*sigh\*)  The "welcome back" banner is what I've seen on other sites.  Ultimately, this is a question about how to better promote upvoting questions....  (There are two messages....  Ok....)

Comment: @JBH ok thanks.  There is also a pop-up that you *occasionally* get if you've voted on a lot of answers and no questions for a while.  It's something along the lines of "questions need love too; please remember to vote on them"; it doesn't actually say "love" but I haven't seen it in a while and don't remember exactly.  I thought that was the one you were asking about.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten "upvote a question" prompt on WB. I'm not sure why we would be different than other Stacks.

Comment: Thanks!  I've never seen it here and so I wondered.  I also couldn't imagine it would be different than other stacks.  I could wish to see it more often, though.

Comment: This is not one of the things that's customized per-site.  We have the same behavior as everybody else.